# cat and grep with a huge file - Broken pipe

Tags: macos, grep, cat

I am tryting to cat and grep a huge 40 GB file. After some output, my process get killed.

Any idea what can be the issue? Using OSX

```
[1]    37392 broken pipe  cat output.txt |
       37393 killed       grep --color=auto -C 20 201804090004054066628236
```

I can confirm its because of `grep` memory usage. Its memory usage shoots up to almost in GB's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `cat` reported the broken pipe because `grep` was killed. This would typically happen if the processes consumed too much memory and the OOM (out of memory) killer was triggered. You could try without the [useless `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html):

```
grep --color=auto -C 20 201804090004054066628236 output.txt
```

Comment: `grep` doesn't store very much information in memory so the OOM seems somewhat unlikely, unless `-C 20` collects lines which are on the order of gigabytes each.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see another reason why `grep` would be killed by something other than the user.